# Automatic update an input number field value based on number values in other input fields

Tags: redux-form

I think I understand how formValueSelector works. But what I have not be able to figure out on how to use formValueSelector to update an INPUT field.

```
connect(
  state => {
    const { firstValue, secondValue } = selector(state, 'first', 'second')
    // do some calculation
    return {
      sum: firstValue + secondValue
    }
  }
)(MyFormComponent)
```

In other words how do I get that `sum` value to be the value of on input field or global Redux state value?

Answer (score 0):

There's an endpoint for such scenarios in redux-form API named as InitializeFromStateForm.
Refer here https://redux-form.com/6.6.3/examples/initializefromstate/

```
InitializeFromStateForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'initializeFromState'  // a unique identifier for this form
})(InitializeFromStateForm)
```

Or else there is no harm in having a new prop for the inputs you like to have an initial state fetched from store something like this.

```
{
  sum: firstValue + secondValue,
  otherInput: "initial value" 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dispatch the change action from your component.

Ex:

```
this.props.change('formname','fieldname', this.props.sum);
```